# Magento product list block only showing top level categories

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to show a group of products from a specific category on the homepage. I tried this code.

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="235" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Rather than show the products within category 235, it shows me links to, and the thumbnail images of, the two categories at the top of the category hierarchy.

My list.phtml file from /app/design/frontend/default/mycustomtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml is as follows: https://bpaste.net/show/66f1d79c7a4e

If I try a different list.phtml that comes with the theme, located here: https://bpaste.net/show/40d5a1e2a8d0 then I get an empty static block that says this category is empty, even though category 235 has 4 products in it.

Is there any obvious glaring error in this code? My goal is to showcase the four products from category 235 on the homepage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your block has been defined correctly. When using multistore setup make sure you added your products to stores. Also check visibility settings of those 4 products, check their stock qty and status of *catalog_category_product* index.